# Is it supported to save a sub site as a templete while its site collection has the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature enabled

Tags: 2013, development, site-template, sub-site

I was reading many articles that saving a sub site as a template might not be supported under certain scenarios, even if the "save site as template" link exists for the sub-site. now in my case i have the following:-

- A Team site collection where i have enabled the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" site collection feature.
- under the above site collection I created a new subsite of type team site, where i did NOT enable the "SharePoint Server Publishing" site features.

now my question if it is supported to save my subsite as a template even if the sub-site's site collection has the ""SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature activated ? now i did a test and i can save my sub-site as a template , and i have created a new subsite based on the template, and i did not face any problems .. but not sure if the new subsites created by the template will be facing any problems i am not aware off ?

Comment: This won't be a problem as long as you can save the subsite as Template.

Answer (score 0):

Once the Sub site is created successfully using saved template, then you will not face any issues. If any issues, you would have faced already while creating the site using template.

Activating the feature "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" in the sub-site, basically it starts inheriting the look&feel, master page, page layouts, design and customization from the top level site collection. As the sub site do not have a dedicated web design, save site as template option is disabled after activating the feature.

In your case, After activating the feature you still see the save site as template option in sub site. Which should not be happening, so i guess the feature is not activated successfully. Try deactivating and activate again using PowerShell.